# jquery show/hide paragraph style only fully applying after rollover (IE ONLY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

have a look at this link (IN IE 8)

[test page](http://garage.a2om.com/highway/test/test/en/temp2.html)

Play around with the expanding Jquery UI checkboxes, they work ok, but sometimes the paragraph tag collopses its margins (or somthing) until you rollover the element, then it fixes itself.

Is there a problem with what I am doing, is there a workaround?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I had to wrap the elements in antoher div, and set a style on that to overflow:hidden